# Android xmpp send message with parameters

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I'm new to openfire chat messages. Right now i have a working chat between 2 phones.

I use the followin line to send the message :

```
Message msgObj = new Message("user"+discover_id + "@" + activity.getResources().getString(R.string.xmpp_server), Message.Type.chat);
```

How can i add extra info ( user_id, sender_name) to the message?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom `ExtensionsElement` and add it to the message. You will also need to implement and register a provider for your custom extension element.